# IP address showing instead of domain address for my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web

I have a domain name from NameCheap, and I am hosting a WP site on Amazon Web Services EC2. I have already changed the A record to so the site pulls up anytime i go to myDomainName.com. Everything works fine until I hit the home bottom on the website. At that point the IP comes up in in the address bar. Any pages i access after that will have the IPaddress/page.

I know I may need to change something in the wp-config.php, but I don't think I have this file on my computer (I used AWS to launch WP, and I don't think I have download anything about WP except some plugins). My website address change option in setting-general on WP is also greyed out so I cannot change it. Anyone has any idea how I could make my domain name display?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing your `home` and `site url` in wp-admin? If you go to wp-admin/options.php you can change the `home` and `site url` fields to your domain name. You can also do it through phpAdmin or editing the DB directly (wp-options table).